# Set value for custom field

Tags: 8, entities

I created a custom field but I don't know how to set a value.
I can read values with

```
$entity->get('field_myfield')->getValue()[0]['data']
```

The field consists of several elements: `value`, `data`, `api_key`

I'm loading the entity and would like to set the values of the field programatically, I tried:

```
$entity->set('field_myfield', ['data' => 'some data'], 'value' => 'some value');
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: This is a single value field with multiple properties? Then the one level array in the example should work, you only need to move the closing square bracket to the end. BTW you get the full two level array with all properties and values from `getValue()` in the first line, which you could, after modifying it, use in the second line to set the field.

Comment: Silly mistake with the brackets. But it still doesn't work. If I try and save the entity, the field is completly empty, i.e. the row in the field table is removed.

Comment: This is easy to debug when you look at the output of `$entity->get('field_myfield')->getValue()`, this is what the second parameter of set() should look like.

Comment: I'll have a look, in the meantime I followed your second suggestion and was able to update one property by using: $data = $entity->get('field_myfield')->getValue()[0]['data']; $data->setValue('some data'); $entity->save()

Comment: One property you could simply: `$data = $entity->field_my_field->data;` or `$entity->field_my_field->data = 'some_data';`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to worry as the entity API should take care of the specific structure and just set it via:

```
$entity->set('field_myfield', 'some value');
$entity->save();
```